# How to keep div same height at all times

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

Right now i have 2 divs next to eachother like so :

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <img src="#"/>
        <article>text</article>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <img src="#"/>
        <article>text</article>
    </div>
</div>
```

the CSS of the images is as follows :

```
max-width: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
```

This gives me the following.

[image]

In the picture the images are of the same size and the same ratio so the containers are exactly the same size.

The images in this field can be uploaded by the user so this means the images can be every size. Once i upload an image that is smaller or a different ratio the containers get a different height (since the width is at 100%).

this needs to be responsive aswell and one of the containers can be filled with a embedded youtube video (an iframe) this needs to be of the same height and width aswell as all the images.

How do i get this result?

Comment: Give `img` class and set `background-size: contain;` This should scale down the images. If this isn't going to work, can we see your custom CSS (if any?), I don't think this boostrap class is image responsive (Can't remember)

Comment: Right now the css of the images is as follows : max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;

Comment: Oh, just set a `max-height` for the `img`. This should retain the aspect ratio of the image and just ensure its smaller then the div height. You'll also need to make sure the `div` has a `max-width` and `max-height`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stretch every item based on the image height, this can be achieved fairly simply using flex. I've made some slight adjustments to your markup, but this example should be illustrative. Basically, use flex-wrap to create a multi-line flex layout, limit every item's width to 50% and make sure the images have a max-width.

```css
* {        
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 max-width: 800px;
}

.flex-item {
 display: flex;
 width: 50%;
}
.article {
 display: block;
 margin: 10px;
 background-color: red;
}
.article img {
 width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 flex">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 flex-item">
     <div class="article">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/500x150"/>
         <article>text<br>more text<br>more text</article>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 flex-item">
     <div class="article">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300"/>
         <article>text</article>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 flex-item">
     <div class="article">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x100"/>
     <article>text</article>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 flex-item">
     <div class="article">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/500x170"/>
         <article>text<br>more text</article>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does work but the thing is that the image always has to remain the same size aswell as the text. the only time this size should change is when the screen size changes.

Comment: I see. You can achieve that using object-fit on the img. I've updated my answer. More info on object-fit can be found at [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/).

Comment: @antidecaf  I like this flex solution too :) +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS property `background-size`.

```
.image {
  background-size: 300px 100px, cover;
}
```

Here a [live demo](http://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/NPMgem).

[More info on scaling images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a video, so you should use the aspect ratio of a video for the image container too. This can be achieve by using of a `padding-bottom` on `56.25%` for an **16x9** aspect ratio. To get an responsive container which can be filled with images and/or videos you must use a wrapper for this content:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row::after {
  clear: both;
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.cell {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}

.media {
  height: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
}

.media img,
.media video,
.media iframe {
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="media">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=16x9&w=320&h=180">
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="media">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=1%C3%971&w=320&h=320">
    </div>
    <p>Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this works for my problem with the video's that are being added!